# iOS Remove Ads Concept

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, iad

So I am implementing remove ads function in my app.
When user clicks remove ads, I first check if already purchased via:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

And if so I save a variable in `NSUSerDefaults`, if not user will make a new payment.

If a user enter an Apple ID who already purchased this (like his friend or something), my variable in `NSUserDefaults` will get changed and ads will be removed on his device.

My question is: Is that how it's done for all users or am I missing something ?
And can a user access the `NSUserDefaults` like editing a `.plist` file or something ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NSUserDefaults` is not secure and rather easy to hack. The Keychain allows small data items to be safely stored and is probably the best choice for persisting this information.

If you encrypt the data the encryption needs to be stored securely and again the best place is the Keychain so it is just easier to store the data in the Keychain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are software around that allow users to modify NSUserDefaults. It would be advisable to encrypt your variable before you store it into NSUserDefaults. Perhaps using device_id + secret as the key to AES to protect your variable, this should be enough to stop most script kiddies.